# No send activation link after registering account on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, mailgun

I register MailGun and configure mail for my domain by MailGun (via SMTP). I test via MailGun plugin for Wordpress, the configuration is ok (success message). I use another SMTP plugin to test, it's ok too. I can send email from administrator@mydomain.com to any email addresses.

However, when a user register account on my site, I received an notification email (send from administrator@mydomain.com to my personal email). But I check email that user registered, there is no activation email was sent. What is this? I don't understand the registering process on wordpress: it should be **user register > send activation email > click on activation link to complete registration** If it's true, why did not my user receive the activation email. How can I fix this?

I google it, but I cannot find out the answer. The mail sending is ok, just Worpress didn't send the activation code to user, just send the notification email to administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like SMTP to send email from your wordpress website. Many hosting providers stop email via php mail().

use following plugin it ight be usefull
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/

Comment: I used this. My problem is not send mail. It's just problem when you user register account. WP only send notification to me (admin), not send activation to user.